# Meteor/Vue/Framework7: No style being used

Tags: css, vue.js, meteor, html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 with meteor and vue and I have included framework7 like this in my main.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { VueMeteor } from 'vue-meteor-tracker';
import App from './App.vue';
import { router } from './router';
import Framework7 from 'framework7/lite-bundle';
import Framework7Vue, { registerComponents } from 'framework7-vue/bundle';
Framework7.use(Framework7Vue);
const app = createApp(App);
registerComponents(app);

Meteor.startup(() => {
  app.use(router);
  app.use(VueMeteor);
  app.mount('#app');
});
```

Unfortunately, the web page being rendered has no kind of framework7 control styling. I even included the css in the main.html file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./.node_modules/Framework7/framework-bundle.css">
```

**EDIT 1: Step-by-step description of failure**

- Meteor project running with vue
- install framework7 with `npm i framework7`
- install framework7-vue with `npm i framework7-vue`
- added `import 'framework7/framework7-bundle.css` (checked for its existance in node_modules folder) to main.js
  ==> Error is thrown: `[vite] Internal server error: Missing "./framework7-bundle.css" export in "framework7" package`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the style from a style tag in your main Vue file.

For example, you have your main Vue file named `App.vue` in the root folder :

You can define the following tag in it :

```html
<style lang="css">
@import 'framework7/css/bundle';
</style>
```

This will load the framework7 bundle css into your own `app.css` file and inject it as style stylesheet.

What I usually do (working in `scss`) is creating a `main.scss` file which will contain global style of my vue app in a css folder, and declare in my `App.vue` the following :

```html
<style lang="scss">
@import 'css/main';
</style>
```

And in the `css/main.scss` file :

```scss
@import 'mynodemodule/path_to_my_css.css';
```

**EDIT**

That kind of syntax should also work (in main.js) (depending of which version of framework7 is used and file location inside framework7 node_module) according to `package.json` exports section of framework7 to get the bundle.css file :

```js
// Import F7 Styles
import 'framework7/css/bundle';
```

**EDIT 2**

Another solution based on vue.js [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-spec.html#src-imports) that should fix your syntax is to declare the css src like this

```html
<!-- import a file from the installed "todomvc-app-css" npm package -->
<style src="todomvc-app-css/index.css" />
```

That would give the following :

```html
<!-- import a file from the installed "framework7" npm package -->
<style src="framework7/css/bundle" />
```

But this syntax doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hi @Laurent Schoelens, thanks for your answer. I am wondering becausew in [this documentation](https://framework7.io/vue/app-layout) the css file is explicitly put into the main.html file. Also, I have problems in adding the css into the app.vue file. The place should be below the "template" part but when I add it there, the app does not start anymore. http://localhost:5173/imports/ui/App.vue?t=1701153786895&vue&type=style&index=0&lang.css throws a 500 error.

Comment: What kind of error do you get in your app (npm / node or something serving your app in local dev mode) ? This is the kind of template I use : https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-spec.html#sfc-syntax-specification

Comment: I'll also add another solution based on vuejs documentation that should make your initial syntax work

Comment: Is there a boilerplate project availalbe somehow that shows a simple app with the combination of meteor/vue and framework7?

Comment: Found twice the same syntax in `app.js` : `import 'framework7/css/framework7.bundle.css';` (updated answer, I think path depends of css path in the framework7 node_module)

Comment: Hi @Laurent, I added a step-by-step description of what I did and what error I am getting. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Found this in package.json `"./css/bundle": "./framework7-bundle.css",`

Comment: Yeah, I also see the framework7-bundle.css in the npm package framework7 but it is just not read.

Comment: Updated the syntax in edit2 according to npm [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/#general-syntax)

Comment: Latest syntax works for me (got f7 css in my injected `chunk-vendors.css`)